# WhereBetween on many-to-many relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

in my sensory model i have this query helper method

```
public function asAroma()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\SensoryEvaluationForm')->wherePivot('sensory_type', '=', 2);
    }
```

How can I add a query to this?
I am using it like this

```
$cs = App\Sensory::first();
$cs->asAroma()->whereBetween('created_at', [$startingDate, $endingDate])->get();
```

It returns nothing. I think there is a different way on building queries with relationships?

What I'm trying to do is to add a wherebetween filter to the resulting relationship.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already found an answer, it seems I need to specify the table name of the created_at attribute I want to refer to in this case `sensory_evaluation_forms.created_at`

Answer (score 2):

Use whereHas() and pass a callback to it.

```
CsModel::with('asAroma')->whereHas('asAroma', function($query) use ($start, $end) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end]);
})->get();
```

Comment: I often see these answers and it's working but I've found an easier way. Check my answer. Thank you for your response :)